# Python Lists: Appending a string and removing ALL quotations

Tags: python, list, append

The code below is taken from a larger project I'm working on.

The aim of this section is to get the output formatted as a list, with no quotation marks anywhere.

However when I try format the output as a list, it has quotation marks around the outside, I've looked through multiple forums and couldn't find anyone whose had the exact issue.

***Coded Input:***

```
colourChart = []
tempColour = tempAlpha

tempColour = "%s" % (', '.join(tempColour)) #! Creates a string, I need it in a List format.
print("What I need it to be formatted as:\n [" + tempColour + "]")

colourChart.append(tempColour) #! Takes previous string, appends to List, adds quotes tho :(
print("What it actually gets formatted as:\n",colourChart)
```

***Output:***

```
What I need it to be formatted as:
 [colourAlpha(0.3), colourAlpha(0.4), colourAlpha(0.5), colourAlpha(0.6)]

What it actually gets formatted as:
 ['colourAlpha(0.3), colourAlpha(0.4), colourAlpha(0.5), colourAlpha(0.6)']
```

This link has the Python script I was testing this with:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1y1-SkyUoDYrR1UU0ssJd6izjfNsbwZUJ?usp=sharing

Comment: I am not sure what you have, need, want, or have tried. Please edit your question to  be more clear

Comment: What is `tempAlpha`? If you need a list, then a string formatting operation should obviously be the wrong way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
colourChart.append(tempColour.split(","))
print("What it actually gets formatted as:\n",colourChart)
```

Answer (score 0):

Join creates a string and the string is what is getting appeneded to colourChart. Use extend.

```
data = ['A', 'B', 'C']

data_result = []

data_result.append(', '.join(data))

data_result
Out[21]: ['A, B, C']

data_result_2 = []

data_result_2.extend(data)



data_result_2
Out[24]: ['A', 'B', 'C']

In [25]:
```